# assigning a compound literal to an array pointer gives both the expected result and rubbish at the same place and time?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, c99, compound-literals

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int a[5], *p, i;
    p = a;
    p = (int []){1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++, p++) {
        printf("%d == %d\n", *p, a[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Lo and behold (YMMV):

```
$ gcc -O -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c99 -o test test.c; ./test
1 == -1344503075
2 == 32767
3 == 4195733
4 == 0
5 == 15774429
```

Printing the array through pointer arithmetic shows that it indeed holds an integer sequence of 1 to 5, yet printing again what is supposedly the same array expressed through indeces gives uninitialized crap. Why?

Comment: I realise this is just demo code, but please never write `int a[5], *p, i;` in real life!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only assign to `p`, never to `a`, so `a` is never initialized.

```
int a[5], *p, i;
// a uninitialized, p uninitialized
p = a;
// a uninitialized, p points to a
p = (int []){1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
// a uninitialized, p points to {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

Answer (score 2):

You never initialize `a`'s elements. Both assignments to `p` change where `p` points; neither assignment does anything to `a` or its elements.

Answer (score 1):

You assign the value of `a` to `p`, and then *immediately* override it with the value of another array of ints. In `printf("%d == %d\n", *p, a[i])` `*p` and `a[i]` no longer reference the same place in memory, and `a` remains uninitialized (hence the garbage).

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning to an array pointer, you do not copy the data to array. So you get the data from one source and rubbish from the other.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is equivalent to this:

```
int a[5];
int b[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    printf("%d == %d\n", b[i], a[i]);
```

Since `a` is uninitialized, you get unpredictable values (in fact it is undefined behaviour to even read those variables).